# SQLalchemy built relationship between classes

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running into a conceptual problem I do not know how to approach, which might be due my lack of knowledge with SQLalchemy. I have two classes: `People` and `Person` and I want them each to have a column to share their respective id's with each other using the relationship function. 
Now, I have an endpoint in `views.py` which instantiates those two classes and establishes a Child / Parent relationship. Looking at the database results however, only `People`, the parent class has the id stored in its respective table, while the `Person` table in column `people` is None. 
I know the id in `person` is only generated after the commit() statement and thus None for `Person`, and was wondering if there is a way to solve this elegantly, or do I need to first query the current `people` instance, retreive its id, set the id in the `person` table and then `commit()` again? 
I hope my question makes sense,thank you.

```
'''
   model.py
'''

class People(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person = relationship('Person', back_populates='people')
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('people.id'))

class Person(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    people = relationship('People', uselist=False, back_populates='person')
```

```
'''
   views.py
'''
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    people = People()
    person = Person(people_id = ?)

    people.person = person

    session.add(person)
    session.add(people)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Why would you want them to share the same id? If that's the case, what use would the relationship have?

Comment: Thank you gittert. People database is more of an `internal` database which keeps uuid and token of each person, with a link to the actual person-data in the person table.In the grad scheme I am interested in building a logging system, where I keep track of each edit on each person as a separate entry and would like to relink relationships between people and person accordingly. So I could have multiple versions of the same person but only one people-row that points to the last version of that person. Sorry for being so verbose.

Comment: You know it is possible to query on the relationship if that is what you want to do? There's really no use case to have a relationship based on the same id. That is why there are database relations. If you need any help on those queries, just post a question here on SO :)

Comment: gittert, you are right that was exactly what I was searching for... uff - sometimes I am confused about myself. Ill be closing this since its just misleading - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I regret that I have not yet understood your question. However, since your code contains some errors, I will first write you my corrected variant.

```
class People(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person = relationship('Person', back_populates='people')
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))

class Person(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    people = relationship('People', back_populates='person')

def index():
    person = Person()
    people = People()
    people.person = person

    session.add(person)
    session.add(people)
    session.commit()
```

The question of gittert seems justified to me. It makes no sense to save the ForeignKey in both tables on the referenced identifiers of the other model.

What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you Detlef for your answer and the quick reply. I basically want to have the person.id stored in the people table and the people.id stored in the person table. The idea is to keep an 'internal' table `people` where I store uuid and token of a specific `person` in the `person table`. And it would be very practical to have this relationship, to query one or the other, depending on the need. Thanks so much

Comment: Are you familiar with abstract super classes and self-references? Perhaps you will reach your goal more on this goal? You don't do what you try. I think you should be dealing with the normalization of databases.

Comment: Also think about what marvls explained to you about virtual relationships. Only one referencing ID (ForeignKey) is saved and the opposite can still be queried in both models.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an actual column in your database for your 'relationships', you won't find them. Your .people and .person are virtual relationships created in Python without any interaction with the SQL database.